# Display svg as image from external url

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, uikit

I have a Firebase storage bucket with svg files in it. The urls for each file are stored in Firestore. I am fetching the urls from firestore so I can display the svgs as images in html. I am using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JS and using UIKit for layout.

What I mean by "display the svgs as images" is:

- I want the user to be able to right click, and click "Save image as".
- I do NOT want my CSS to affect the svgs in any way.
- I do not need to manipulate the SVGs programmatically.

I am using UIKit and have tried both of their documented methods of displaying svgs:

Method 1: as an [inline svg image](https://getuikit.com/docs/svg)

```
var source = logo.imageURL;

var div = document.createElement("div");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.width = 160;
img.src = source;
img.setAttribute("uk-svg", "");
div.appendChild(img)
parent.appendChild(div);
```

This results in the ability to see the svgs on the page, but:

- You can't right click them to save them
- UIKit's CSS is affecting the colors (all fills are gray).

Method 2: [lazy loading using Image component](https://getuikit.com/docs/image#inline-svg)

```
var source = logo.imageURL;

var div = document.createElement("div");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.width = 160;
img.src = source;
img.setAttribute("uk-img", "data-src:" + source);
img.setAttribute("uk-svg", "");
div.appendChild(img)
parent.appendChild(div);
```

This results in the svgs showing up as blank white squares.

Other tests I have done:

I grabbed one of the svg files and added it to my frontend `/images` folder and hardcoded the `source` variable to use the local file. The SVGs showed up fine, and met all my criteria above, so I assume there's nothing wrong with the file itself.

Any help or advice with this would be great.

Comment: Method 1 and 2 both inject the SVG as inline (according to UIkit docs). What about just creating an image and set the path of the SVG as the `src` of the image, without any UIkit tricks? If that doesn't work then please create an minimal, reproducible example for us to experience your issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/matthew-nearents/pen/zYowgNY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla HTML5, if your want CSS isolation you need to place it in *shadowDOM* (supported in all modern browsers)

Either attach shadowDOM to your own `<span>` element;

Or take it one step further and create your own re-usable HTML Element `<shadow-svg>` (or any name you want)

Note: the SVG being an IMG src should be enough to not be affected by global CSS; so shadowDOM not strictly required. It ensures the IMG can not be styled by global CSS in this example.

```html
<span id=SVG></span>

<shadow-svg src="https://svgshare.com/i/U7z.svg"></shadow-svg>
<shadow-svg src="https://svgshare.com/i/U7o.svg"></shadow-svg>
<shadow-svg src="https://svgshare.com/i/U7p.svg"></shadow-svg>

<style>
  #SVG {
    height: 130px;
    background: pink
  }
</style>

<script>
  SVG
    .attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    })
    .innerHTML = `<style>:host{display:inline-block}img{height:130px;width:130px}</style>` +
    `<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/U7L.svg">`;

// OR

  customElements.define("shadow-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({
          mode: "open"
        })
        .innerHTML = `<style>:host{display:inline-block}img{height:130px;width:130px}</style>` +
        `<img src="${this.getAttribute("src")}">`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I do this, my images appear broken. So I copied your snippet into CodePen and used one of my URLs and it also appeared broken. Here is the URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ui-logos.appspot.com/o/logos%2Fmnear_4.svg?alt=media&token=ee5d901d-316b-4f4a-afee-eb3ec5d72989

Maybe that means the svg is formatted incorrectly?

Comment: Yep, looks like my svgs are missing the `xmlns:xlink` attribute.

Comment: Actually that's not the problem. Looks like if I simply export them at a smaller size (was 300x300px, now 100x100px they show up correctly even without the `xmlns:xlink` attribute.

Comment: And third time's a charm, I was uploading to firebase storage through an interface I created. And I was uploading as type `image/jpeg` instead of `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: Good find; yes, ``xlink`` is no longer required in modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks, accepted this answer as the shadow DOM helped with the CSS conflicts.