# Manipulating SVGs in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, web-scraping

I currently have a Python bs4 script which loads a .svg file and lets me change some text, colors and a few other things in it.

Today I decided to start working on a SaaS version of this script. I decided that I will probably use Python/Django for the back end in case I need some work done on the svg in the back end via bs4, and React for the front end, since it's really the only front end technology I am familiar with.

But I am having issues with loading, editing and showing the .svg files in React. I used `axios` for loading the .svg(it's currently locally hosted but in the future it's going to be on AWS or something) and `jssoup` npm package for finding elements in my svg.

Here's my current code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import JSSoup from "jssoup";

function App() {
  const [pic, setPic] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("./newfile.svg")
      .then((res) => {
        var soup = new JSSoup(res.data, false);
        let elements = soup.findAll("g");
        console.log(elements);
        setPic(soup.prettify());
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error, ", err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${pic}`} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

First question is, am I even using the correct tool for the job? Is JavaScript even capable of such work? Next question is, how am I supposed to actually show the .svg after doing some work on it with jssoup?

Comment: You have a lot of cool tools for sure. I have no clue WHAT you want to change in the SVG. But displaying it in an IMG takes some alterations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66359132/how-to-properly-encode-content-of-img-src-dataimage-svgxml

Comment: Hey @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for the link, as it turns out I will probably need to add some onClick functionality eventually so I need the svg to stay as a svg. The more I research about this problem the more I feel like this is not the correct tool for the job. Thanks either way.

Comment: JavaScript + SVG can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487955/show-multiple-svgs-in-single-img-tag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263255/how-to-make-an-svg-interactive-to-gather-comments-annotations-on-depicted-elemen) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247729/display-svg-as-image-from-external-url) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205662/calculate-percentage-in-progress-circle). There is only one serious problem with JavaScript.... you have to learn JavaScript